# How to reset CSS when performing a second search (remove search result from 1st search)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building a simple weather app in ES6 that is supposed to return a song from Spotify that fits the current weather alongside with the forecast. However, when a user performs two searches in a row for different locations  it will still show the song from the first search.

Currently, I'm hiding the song tracks in CSS with display: none and changing the display to block in JS depending on the search result through if-statements.
How can I remove the first song, so from the first search?

I tried changing the if-statements to a switch statement but it stopped displaying the songs altogether. Another option I thought of was using classList but I'm not sure how...

CSS

```
#musicRain,
#musicClear,
#musicThunderstorm,
#musicSnow,
#musicClouds,
#musicAtmosphere {
  display: none;
}
```

JS

```
function showCurrentWeather(response) {
  let currentTemperature = document.querySelector("#currentTemperature");
  currentTemperature.innerHTML = `${Math.round(response.data.main.temp)}°C`;
[etc... ]

if (response.data.weather[0].main === "Clear") {
    document.getElementById("musicClear").style.display = "block";
  }
  if (response.data.weather[0].main === "Drizzle") {
    document.getElementById("musicDrizzle").style.display = "block";
  }
  if (response.data.weather[0].main === "Rain") {
    document.getElementById("musicRain").style.display = "block";
  }
  if (response.data.weather[0].main === "Clouds") {
    document.getElementById("musicClouds").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("musicAtmosphere").style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

Comment: Simple (if not very elegant) way would be to set style.display = 'none' on all the elements before showing the one you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Chris! Could you specify a little bit? Setting style.display to none through another if statement? 
I'm still an absolute beginner :-)

Comment: I wont post it as an answer because @StillLearning has a better answer. But the idea was to add ```document.getElementById("musicAtmosphere").style.display = "none";``` before the if statement setting it to ```document.getElementById("musicAtmosphere").style.display = "block";```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to set every element's `display` field to either `block` or `none` so that earlier settings won't linger. Since they all start with "music" you could do this:

```
  const types = ["Clear","Drizzle","Rain","Clouds","Atmosphere"];
  types.forEach( type => {
    const musicType = `music${type}`
    if (response.data.weather[0].main === type) {
      document.getElementById(musicType).style.display = "block";
    }
    else {
      document.getElementById(musicType).style.display = "none";
    }
  });
```

Comment: Oh wow that's cool! I haven't been using const yet, thank you! I'll read up on it, it's working!

Comment: great!  if the answer is good for you please mark it as correct